# Количество записей которые прочитали рефералы

Tags: count, mysql

Нужно вывести количество статьей которые прочитали рефералы пользователя.
Есть три таблици: `users, referals(id_user,id_referals(пользователь который пригласил в систему)), history(id_user,id_articles(статья которая прочитана))`.

Мой запрос ну он не верный:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT(history.id_articles)), users.login FROM referals,users,history WHERE referals.id_referals = 1
    AND users.id = referals.id_user
```

Пользователь не прочитал ни одной статьи, но выводится 3.

Comment: Где `history.id_user = users.id` в WHERE ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
users (id, name)
referals(id_user,id_referals)
history(id_user,id_articles)

SELECT referals.id_referals, COUNT(history.id_articles)
FROM referals, history
WHERE referals.id_referals = 1 AND
history.id_user = referals.id_user
GROUP BY referals.id_referals
```

что то типа такого?